# Screen will not start. no clue why

Tags: bash, minecraft

I have this script that runs every hour or so, and it is supposed to check to see if a minecraft server is running in a screen, and if its not, then it should start the server in the screen.

```
if ! screen -list | grep -q "mc"; then
        echo "starting"
        screen -dmS mc /home/mc/run_server.sh
fi
```

I am still new to Bash and i have been trying to debug this and have not come up with why it will not start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. What exactly doesn't start? Have you put it in a file?

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! screen -list | grep -q "mc"; then
    echo "starting"
    screen -dmS mc /home/mc/run_server.sh
else
    echo "minecraft server is already running!"
fi
```

Save it in, for example, your home directory as `mc.sh` file.
Set executable permissions for it:

```
chmod +x mc.sh
```

And try to run it:

```
./mc.sh
```

The `! screen -list | grep -q "mc"` condition works if there are no entries named "mc" found in `screen -list` (the command that lists all running sessions), so if there are NO "mc" screen sessions at the moment, it will show you a "starting" message and start a new screen session in which the `run_server.sh` will be ran.

Otherwise it will show "minecraft server is already running!" and do nothing.

If you have put it in a crontab and it doesn't work there, try to use every command with an absolute path.

```
0 * * * * /home/alandoyle/mc.sh
```

And replace every `screen` usage in script with a full path to `screen` (for example, `/usr/bin/screen`; you can determine your one using a `which screen` command)

Comment: and THIS is why i should not try to make this stuff at 4 in the morning....... haha forgot to mhmod +x the script.... xD thanks!!!!!!